# Multiple URL mapping with same filters spring security 3.x

Tags: java, spring-security, jboss6.x

I have been using Spring Security 3.x for handling user authentication for my projects .

I recently received the requirements as when user login and accessing specific pages it should active myFilter

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <d:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <d:filter-chain pattern="/mapping1.jsp,/mappin2.jsp,/mapping3.jsp" filters="myFilter " />
    </d:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

how to map multiple mapping to same filter in this perspective.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is little bit different in your case:

```
<d:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
    <d:filter-chain pattern="/mapping1.jsp" filters="myFilter"/>
    <d:filter-chain pattern="/mapping2.jsp" filters="myFilter"/>
    <d:filter-chain pattern="/mapping3.jsp" filters="myFilter"/>
</d:filter-chain-map>
```